# How much zener needs current to regulate voltage?

Tags: zener

Is there some lower limit how much current is needed to keep zener regulating voltage. I think I have read that it will require some amount to operate reliably but how can I say what is not enough and can this be somehow derived from the datasheet information or is it more like some universal rule of thumb?

Comment: Find a data sheet and link it here and someone will show.

Comment: The datasheet will likely specify the optimal operating current and will provide you with the local resistance slope at that operating point so that you can work out how much variation in voltage to expect if your current source itself varies by some predictable amount. A typical (getting old, I suspect) datasheet one one family of zeners is [here](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/1N4736AT-D.PDF).

Comment: Had you searched this site for 'zener current' or something similar before posting your question? This has been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: Datasheets seem to present voltage vs. current in mA. you can't really say what happens when we go to 100 or even 10 uA range.

Comment: Every manufacturer specifies the working current at Vz as is appropriate for their own devices. Some datasheets have typical curves of reverse current vs. reverse voltage. There is no standard (other than *read the datasheet*).

Answer (score 2):

> *How much zener needs current to regulate voltage?*

Just pick a data sheet (like the [1N53xx](https://docs.rs-online.com/b551/0900766b814f4429.pdf) series) and look at the graphs: -

[image]

I've highlighted the 1N5339 zener diode. In the graph it shows typical zener voltage versus zener current: -

- 1 amp about 5.6 volts
- 100 mA a shade lower
- 10 mA a bit lower (maybe 5.5 volts)
- 1 mA probably about 5.2 volts
- 100 uA about 4.9 volts

Some zener diodes may not show these graphs so if it is important, choose a zener diode that does have adequate information. If the characteristic isn't stable enough in terms of zener voltage at lower currents you have the option of choosing an active shunt regulator (such as the [TL431](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TL431-D.PDF)) and a transistor to give it more current handling capability: -

[image]